# Is it possible to create PHP extensions in Haskell?

Tags: php, c, haskell, php-extension, ffi

Is it possible to create PHP extensions with Haskell?

Usually PHP extensions are written using C. Is using Haskell FFI to provide functionality for a stub C extension possible (or even a good idea)?

What are the caveats to such an approach? Does Zend perform some magic in the background that would disrupt such a scheme?

Comment: Oh the haskell fanboys will love this idea!

Comment: We do, but not quite as much as *replacing* PHP with Haskell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can certainly do this, though I'm not sure anyone has tried. Haskell interoperates with C via [its FFI mechanism](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/interfacing-with-c-the-ffi.html), and you can certainly:

- [Call Haskell from C](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C)

so if you can call C from PHP, and that C calls Haskell, you're in business.

---

Why would you want to do this? Faster, safer, simple code for your core algorithms or safety-critical code, perhaps. Or to take advantage of say, a parallel or multicore server backend via Haskell.

Comment: Well in this case, because I already have a Haskell program that I currently call using shell_exec from PHP. Now we are moving towards PHP extensions, so I am trying to save the existing codebase (atleast in the short run before I have had a chance to convert it to C). Not to mention how much more painful C is compared to Haskell (or anything for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. Just make sure you wrap everything and translate arguments between php -> c -> haskell and the way back correctly.